# .pyファイルと.ipynbファイルでカレントディレクトリがずれるのはなぜ？

Tags: python

ディレクトリを移動してcsvデータを保存するという作業を行うために、ipynbファイルでいろいろ試行錯誤しておりました。
ipynbで問題なく動くことが確認できたため、pyファイルにコードをフルコピーして実行したところディレクトリが見つからないというエラーがでました。
そこで、ipynbとpyのカレントディレクトリを確認（sample.ipynb, sample.py）すると1階層ずれていることがわかりました。

ディレクトリ確認のために実行したコードは以下のコードです。

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir('../')
print(os.getcwd())
```

実行結果は、このようになりました。

#### sample.ipynb

```
d:\Data\XXX\Python
d:\Data\XXX
```

#### sample.py

```
D:\Data\XXX
D:\Data
```

たしかにずれているのですが、両ファイルのディレクトリは同じ階層に存在します（以下参考）。

```
D:
└─Data
   └─XXX
      └─Python
         ├─sample.ipynb
         └─sample.py
```

実行に関しては、移動の際、".."を"."に変えるだけで動くので問題ないのですが、同じ階層にあるにもかかわらずディレクトリがずれることが気になって仕方ありません。
なぜ、このようなことになるのでしょうか。

追記
どちらもVSCodeでおこないました。
.pyファイルは、VSCodeでデバッグ開始をクリックしました。

settings.jsonは以下となっております。

#### settings.json

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "launch": {
    
        "configurations": [],
        "compounds": []
    }
}
```

Comment: 使っているIDEやツールと実行方法に依存していると思われます。`.ipynb`はJupyterNotebook/Labで`.py`はVSCodeとかのデバッグ実行などでは？ その辺の詳細(settings.jsonなども？)を追記してください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。追記いたしました。

Comment: 済みません`launch.json`も加えてください。おそらく拡張子で変わる設定によって`cwd`の内容とか違っているのでは？ [Launch configurations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations)

Comment: 同時刻についた回答はあまり理解できていないのですが、一先ず指示通り追記いたしました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.ipynb` (Jupyter Notebook, JupyterLab) の場合
Notebookの位置するディレクトリではなく
Jupyterを起動したディレクトリ (Jupyter Kernelのディレクトリ)がカレントディレクトリです
(以下の場合, jupyter labを起動した位置になる)

```bash
$ cd /home/USER/lang/Python
$ jupyter lab
```

`.py`の場合もそれは同様
(以下の場合 `Python/sample.py`を実行してても, `getcwd()`は Python実行した位置)

```bash
─home
   └─USER
      └─lang
         └─Python
            └─sample.py

$ cd /home/USER/lang/

$ python Python/sample.py
/home/USER/lang
/home/USER
```

---

##### 追記

VS Codeでの `.ipynb` は, (そのプロジェクト) ワークスペース の位置のはず

Comment: ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

`os.getcwd()` が返す結果はあくまで **作業ディレクトリ** であり、必ずしも実行したプログラムの保存場所とは限りません。

.py ファイル等と同じディレクトリにいる状態で実行すれば同じ結果になるでしょうが、実行の仕方次第で結果は変わってきます。

Comment: ありがとうございました。